# Area under graph of function with uncountably many discontinuities

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

First, consider an informal argument: Given $f$: $[a, b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$, let $A$ denote a function capturing the intuitive geometric notion of area under the graph of $f$, so if $x$ is a point of continuity for $f$, then one would expect the expression (whatever it is rigorously) $A(x+h)-A(x)\approx hf(x+\theta h)$ to be the area of a small rectangle with bottom left corner at $(x, 0)$, and hence $A'(x)=f(x)$. So this local FTofCalculus-type property can be thought of as a consequence of the intuitive notion of area.

Now, inspired by the above, define an *area function* for $f$ to be an $F$ with $F'(x)=f(x)$ at every point of continuity for $f$ (only); call $f$ *integrable* if there exists a unique (up to additive constants) area function for $f$, and define *area* between $a$ and $b$ to be $F(b)-F(a)$. It turns out that the functions integrable is this sense are those with countably many points of discontinuity (see e.g. B. Thomson's *The Calculus Integral* or E. Zakon's *Mathematical Analysis*).

The point is that, whatever *area* should be, there is no danger of getting it wrong here, because thanks to the uniqueness part of the definition, for this class of functions there is no choice on the question of what the area should be: that something, which we think of as the area under the graph, is well-defined for such functions.

Based on this I am tempted to form the belief that these are precisely the functions $f$: $[a, b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, for which the concept of *area under the graph* is a sensible one, at least in the elementary calculus sense,

EDIT: I'm now convinced that it makes more sense to think this of the Riemann-integrable functions.

in that it is consistent with the usual geometric intuition of an area, although it includes some bizarre enough functions (e.g. Thomae's popcorn function) for which it probably does not apply. I wonder, is this a reasonable conclusion?

If not, suppose $f$: $[a, b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is some function with uncountably many points of discontinuity. Of course, we could stick to limits of rectangle sums and define area to be the values of the Riemann- or Lebesgue-Integral etc (if it exists). However, now the above *area function* is not unique any more, and so there is something else that we could equally well set the area equal to. Is there really a choice involved here or is there a reason why, even in this case, the *area under the graph of f* should be something particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going by Riemann integration, then a function is integrable if and only if its set of discontinuities has measure $0$ (in the sense of Lebesgue measure). This is [Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability). In Riemann integration I'd say there's not much room for choice, either a function is or isn't integrable (according tot he criterion), and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus guarantees that the value of $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ does not depend on your choice of (almost everywhere) antiderivative $F$.

Notice that there are uncountable sets with zero measure, so one may yet integrate them via Riemann to find an 'essentially unique' notion of area.

---

If you're going by Lebesgue integration, then *area* depends on what measure you're integrating by, and so there is plenty of 'choice' here.

Comment: OK, but it's not quite what I'm asking: take a Riemann-integrable function $f$ with uncountably many points of discontinuity. In this case (for a reason described above) there is not a unique choice for *area under the graph* of $f$. Why should it be given by the Riemann-integral of $f$?

Comment: You don't need to, and in fact many times the Riemann-integral of $f$ will not exist.

Comment: Elaborating on it, for many, many functions simple functions (any continuous function, for instance), the Riemann integral exists and gives a value that corresponds to our intuitive notion of area under the graph of a function. With this in mind, and like in many other areas of mathematics, we hand wave it and say 'So, whenever the integral exists, we say it is the area under the graph of $f$!', even if $f$ has (uncountably many) discontinuities. Under ***this*** interpretation, it makes sense to think of the area under the graph of $f$ as the Riemann integral of $f$.

Comment: Which is not to say other integrals do not exist. Notice that whenever a Riemann integral exists, the corresponding Lebesgue integral also exists and equals the former, so if you're between them and Riemann does the job, it doesn't matter which one you use. That said, one can use other integrals or other measures to assign meaningful values to integrals that Riemann integration cannot solve or that differ from Riemann integration, but the key point here is that meaningful depends on context. If the context is 'intuitive/geometric notion of area', then traditional integration is the way to go.

Comment: I agree that it makes sense, and in fact for functions with at most countably many discontinuities there is only one such *interpretation* and so the concept of *area* makes sense as, then, it does not depend on the choice of interpretation. The question is if *area* becomes a meta-concept once there is more than one interpretation or if, even then, there is something, which it should be equal to.

Comment: I think this is too broad/bordering on philosphical musings, rather than mathematical discussion. What is the *area* under the graph of $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow [0,1]$ given by $f(x)=\chi_{[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}}(x)$?

Comment: Let me put it another way: measuring area under the graph of a function is simply an instance of measuring the $n$-dimensional volume (for $n=2$) of some sets. How do you measure the volume of a set? Is there a canonical or otherwise unique interpretation of volume?

Comment: There clearly is a class of objects for which the area (or volume, for that matter) is canonical (wrt. the most standard Euclidean notion). If the object is bizarre enough, it certainly might not be. Basically I'm giving a class of functions, for which I think the area is just about canonical, and am asking if there is a canonical notion beyond that class, and why.

Comment: How do you define canonical? That is precisely my point. Is canonical continuous? Rieamann-integrable? Formalizing what defines the canonical, intuitive notion of area is important if you wish to generalize beyond intuition.

Comment: I define canonical in this context to mean what I think you meant by canonical in your previous comment, that is, having an interpretation, which for some mathematical reason is more valuable than another.

Comment: That is much too vague. I'm not sure I can help.

Comment: It might be vague, but it also might have a definite answer.